# Can't find apex class with invocable method in Process Builder on production org

Tags: process-builder, invocable-method

Can't find apex class with invocable method in Process Builder on production org. On develop org it works fine.

[image]
Please, what can be wrong?

```
global class SearchObjectWhenCreate {

global class Request {
    @InvocableVariable
    public String objectId;
    @InvocableVariable
    public String searchType;
}

@InvocableMethod
public static void searchObject(List<Request> requests) {

    SearchButtonsController searchButtonsCtrl = new SearchButtonsController();
    List<verf__VF_Search__c> listOfSearches = new List<verf__VF_Search__c>();

    if (Schema.sObjectType.VF_Search__c.fields.Id.isAccessible()){
        listOfSearches = [SELECT Id
                        FROM verf__VF_Search__c
                        WHERE Name =: requests[0].searchType
                        LIMIT 1];
    }
    if(!listOfSearches.isEmpty()){
        searchButtonsCtrl.vf_searchId = listOfSearches[0].Id;
        searchButtonsCtrl.strObjectId = requests[0].objectId;
        searchButtonsCtrl.getObjectInfo();
        searchButtonsCtrl.isCalledFromProcessBuilder = true;
        searchButtonsCtrl.searchRequest();
        request(searchButtonsCtrl.xmlStringxmlRes, searchButtonsCtrl.vf_searchName);
    }
}

@future(callout=true)
public static void request(String xmlStringxmlRes, String searchName) {
    Http httpProtocol = new Http();
    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
    HttpResponse response = new HttpResponse();
    String body = 'request=' + xmlStringxmlRes;

    String endpoint = 'https://viqzrh5hp3.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/verified_first';
    request.setEndPoint(endpoint);
    request.setBody(body);
    request.setMethod('POST');

    try {
         if(!Test.IsRunningTest()){
            response = httpProtocol.send(request);
            parseXMLResponce(response.getBody(), searchName);
        }
    } catch(System.CalloutException e) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried recompiling your apex classes? Via Setup -> apex classes -> Compile all classes (top left)

Comment: Thanks for idea, I performed recompiling. But it did not help.

Comment: It happened with me as well, my class name is "invokeFreezeAccount", However in process builder it was showing name as "FreezeAccount"
It will be good if you contact Salesforce Support.

Comment: try run tests for the class in question in PROD

Comment: Class successfuly passed test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_InvocableMethod.htm):

> An invocable method can be public in a managed package, but it won’t appear as an action in the Cloud Flow Designer’s list of available actions while building or editing a flow. These invocable actions can still be referred to by flows within the same managed package. Global invocable methods in a managed package can be used in flows outside the managed package, anywhere in the organization, and appear in the Cloud Flow Designer’s list of available actions to add to a flow.

So with global invocable methods and global invocable variables all works on production. Solution was found. Thanks to all!

Answer (score 2):

I had the similar problem, but fixed it for public class:
1) close Process Builder
2) go to Setup / Develop / Apex Classes and click "Compile all classes"
​3) go to your process and select your class